# LINQ GroupBy и ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, lambda, linq2sql

нужно получить данные вида

```
    public new class out_rm
    {
        public int id_a { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<pr_abon> pr_abon { get; set; }
    }
```

при анонимном типе группировка срабатывает и я вижу правильные данные.

```
        var out = Ctx.pr_abon
            .GroupBy(g => g.id_a)
            .Select(s => new 
                {
                    id_a = s.Key
                })
            .ToList();
```

как получить на выходите именно типизорованный объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Судя по всему, вам нужно

   ```
   Ctx.pr_abon
      .GroupBy(g => g.id_a)
      .Select(s => s.Key)
      .ToList();
   ```
2. Вы не получите `ObservableCollection` из LINQ-выражения бесплатно. Но вы можете, например, построить новый экземпляр `ObservableCollection`:

   ```
   var coll = new ObservableCollection<int>(
                   Ctx.pr_abon
                      .GroupBy(g => g.id_a)
                      .Select(s => s.Key));
   ```

   При этом промежуточная материализация (`.ToList()`) оказывается не нужна.

Заметьте, что для конкретно вашего запроса есть более простой путь. Например:

```
new ObservableCollection<int>(Ctx.pr_abon.Select(e => e.id_a).Distinct())
```

или если все `id_a` разные, то просто

```
new ObservableCollection<int>(Ctx.pr_abon.Select(e => e.id_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно заменить ObservableCollection<> на List<>

```
public new class out_rm
{
    public int id_a { get; set; }

    public List<pr_abon> pr_abon { get; set; }
}
```

и получить вот так:

```
    var out = Ctx.pr_abon
        .GroupBy(g => g.id_a)
        .Select(s => new out_rm
            {
                id_a = s.Key,
                pr_abon = s.ToList()
            })
        .ToList();
```